# SQL to return matches from multiple queries

Tags: sql, vbscript

I need to return values that appear across two or more queries from the same table. Feeling a bit like a noob here but just can't see the wood for the trees.

I have a table of users assigned to different groups. I need to return only the users that appear in all of the requested groups:

```
User   Group
frank  1
Jane   2
Tom    2
frank  2
Jane   1
Tom    3
```

This is want I need to output:

```
Result for Group 1 & 2:
frank
Jane

Result for Group 2 & 3:
Jane
Tom
```

Seems a very 101 question, but grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user
from users
where group_id in (1,2)
group by user
having count(*) = 2;
```

You need to adjust the `having count(*) = 2` condition to the number of groups that you want.

If a user can be assigned to the same group more than once, then Madhivanan's comment need to be taken into account:

```
select user
from users
where group_id in (1,2)
group by user
having count(distinct group_id) = 2;
```

(I used the column name `group_id` because `group` is a reserved word and should be used as a column name).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fantastic,, seems to work a treat :)
The column names were just for reference, but take your point. The records are unique per group as well, but good point for future reference.
Again, many thanks for the quick response :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
select user from table
where group in (1,2)
group by user
having count(distinct group)=2
```